# Plotting a elliptic curve on a torus

Tags: graphing-functions, elliptic-curves

I'm studying the application of elliptic curves in crpytographie and I found a lot of pretty good looking plots of elliptic curves on tori:
[image]

Some of these examples can be found [here](https://trustica.cz/en/2018/05/10/elliptic-curves-discrete-logarithm-problem/) and [here](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eegoins/prime/2015%20PRiME%20Young%20Mathematicians%20Conference%20Poster.pdf). I tried to create these images using SageMath but I failed miserably. A torus can be created with this code:

```
sage: from sage.plot.plot3d.shapes import Torus
sage: Torus(1, .7, color='red', opacity=.5, grid = true).show(aspect_ratio=1)
```

The problem: I have no idea, how to get a grid structure on the torus and I have no idea how to get points/functions on the torus. Can someone help me?

Comment: As for the "grid", it's merely markings of equidistant angles from the major and minor radii. Plotting functions on the grid should be incredibly easy using polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?